aws s3 ls: getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error
When I try to run aws s3 ls to see the list of my buckets, i am getting the following error in my ACL: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
I have checked my key and signing methods, they are all okay. can anyone assist me here please
I am expecting to see the list of my buckets inside the aws

What version of the AWS cli are you using?

Related, might be helpful: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/602

@stdunbar i think the latest because I recently downloaded it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
